# Android AlertDialog wait for result in calling activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to use an `AlertDialog` in my app to select the quantity of an item. The problem is that the activity that calls the `AlertDialog` doesn't wait for it to update the item before it adds it to the SQLite Database and change intents.

At the moment, the `QuantitySelector` (`AlertDialog`) appears, then disappears straight away and changes the `MealActivity` class (which is just a `ListView` that reads from the database) through the intent change with an update to the database with quantity 0.

I need the `Activity` to wait for the `AlertDialog` to close before it updates the database.

What would be the correct way of implementing this?

Here is some code for you:

`QuantitySelector` (which runs the alertdialog):

```
public class QuantitySelector{

    protected static final int RESULT_OK = 0;
    private Context _context;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private HashMap<String, Double> measures;
    private Item item;
    private View v;
    private EditText quan;
    private NumberPicker pick;
    private int value;
    private Quantity quantity;

    /**
     * Function calls the quantity selector AlertDialog
     * @param _c: The application context
     * @param item: The item to be added to consumption
     * @return The quantity that is consumed
     */
    public void select(Context _c, Item item, Quantity quantity){
        this._context = _c;
        this.item = item;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        db = new DatabaseHandler(_context);
        //Get the measures to display
        createData();
        //Set up the custom view
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(_context);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quantity_selector, null);
        //Set up the input fields
        quan = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.quantityNumber);
        pick = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
        //Set up the custom measures into pick
        pick.setMaxValue(measures.size()-1);
        pick.setDisplayedValues(measures.keySet().toArray(new String[0]));
        //Start the alert dialog
        runDialog();
    }

    public void createData(){
        measures = new HashMap<String, Double>();       
        //Get the measurements from the database
        if(item!=null){
        measures.putAll(db.getMeasures(item));
        }
        //Add grams as the default measurement
        if(!measures.keySet().contains("grams")){
            //Add grams as a standard measure
            measures.put("grams", 1.0);
        }
    }

    public void runDialog(){
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context).setTitle("Select Quantity")
                .setView(v)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        //Change the consumption to the new quantity
                        if(!quan.getText().toString().matches("")){
                            value = Integer.parseInt(quan.getText().toString());
                            //Check if conversion from other units is needed
                            String s[] = pick.getDisplayedValues();
                            String a = s[pick.getValue()];
                            //Convert the chosen measure back to grams
                            if(!a.equals("grams")){
                                for(String m : measures.keySet()){
                                    if(m==a){
                                        value = (int) (value * measures.get(m));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        quantity.setQuantity(value);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).create();
            dialog.show();
    }

}
```

The method from favouritesAdapter (which calls the alertdialog):

```
add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                QuantitySelector q = new QuantitySelector();
                Quantity quan = new Quantity();
                q.select(_context, db.getItem(p.getID()), quan);
                db.addConsumption(p.getID(), p.getFavouriteShortName(), quan.getQuantity(), "FAVOURITE");
                Intent intent = new Intent(_context,MealActivity.class);
                _context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

All help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Async task and update data in doInBackGround and in onPostExecute method Show Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to go about this is to actually start the next intent when the person presses the positive button.  In short, you need to be starting your next Activity in the OnClickListener that is attached to your positive button of your AlertDialog.

```
public void runDialog(){
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context).setTitle("Select Quantity")
            .setView(v)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    //Change the consumption to the new quantity
                    if(!quan.getText().toString().matches("")){
                        value = Integer.parseInt(quan.getText().toString());
                        //Check if conversion from other units is needed
                        String s[] = pick.getDisplayedValues();
                        String a = s[pick.getValue()];
                        //Convert the chosen measure back to grams
                        if(!a.equals("grams")){
                            for(String m : measures.keySet()){
                                if(m==a){
                                    value = (int) (value * measures.get(m));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    quantity.setQuantity(value);
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    //The only catch now is passing through your _context
                    Intent intent = new Intent(_context,MealActivity.class);
                    _context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).create();
        dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try. What about the db.addConsumption(), won't it execute without the new quantity because it isn't waiting?

Comment: You should also probably put that in there, too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your problem is you are calling the start activity for MealACtivity before destroying the alert dialogue so can update your code  as follows:

Update your method which calls the alertdialogue by this code:

```
    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            QuantitySelector q = new QuantitySelector();
            Quantity quan = new Quantity();
            q.select(_context, db.getItem(p.getID()), quan);
            db.addConsumption(p.getID(), p.getFavouriteShortName(), quan.getQuantity(), "FAVOURITE");
           /* Intent intent = new Intent(_context,MealActivity.class);
            _context.startActivity(intent);*/

        }
    });
```

and update your Quantity Selector class with the following :

```
public class QuantitySelector{

    protected static final int RESULT_OK = 0;
    private Context _context;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private HashMap<String, Double> measures;
    private Item item;
    private View v;
    private EditText quan;
    private NumberPicker pick;
    private int value;
    private Quantity quantity;

    /**
     * Function calls the quantity selector AlertDialog
     * @param _c: The application context
     * @param item: The item to be added to consumption
     * @return The quantity that is consumed
     */
    public void select(Context _c, Item item, Quantity quantity){
        this._context = _c;
        this.item = item;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        db = new DatabaseHandler(_context);
        //Get the measures to display
        createData();
        //Set up the custom view
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(_context);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quantity_selector, null);
        //Set up the input fields
        quan = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.quantityNumber);
        pick = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
        //Set up the custom measures into pick
        pick.setMaxValue(measures.size()-1);
        pick.setDisplayedValues(measures.keySet().toArray(new String[0]));
        //Start the alert dialog
        runDialog();
    }

    public void createData(){
        measures = new HashMap<String, Double>();       
        //Get the measurements from the database
        if(item!=null){
        measures.putAll(db.getMeasures(item));
        }
        //Add grams as the default measurement
        if(!measures.keySet().contains("grams")){
            //Add grams as a standard measure
            measures.put("grams", 1.0);
        }
    }

    public void runDialog(){
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context).setTitle("Select Quantity")
                .setView(v)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        //Change the consumption to the new quantity
                        if(!quan.getText().toString().matches("")){
                            value = Integer.parseInt(quan.getText().toString());
                            //Check if conversion from other units is needed
                            String s[] = pick.getDisplayedValues();
                            String a = s[pick.getValue()];
                            //Convert the chosen measure back to grams
                            if(!a.equals("grams")){
                                for(String m : measures.keySet()){
                                    if(m==a){
                                        value = (int) (value * measures.get(m));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        quantity.setQuantity(value);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(_context,MealActivity.class);
                        _context.startActivity(intent);

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).create();
            dialog.show();
    }
```